Installation of terra package using conda and renv returns error for `int8_t` not defined
I'm working in a conda environment in Windows trying to initialize an renv environment (with renv::init()) a colleague shared with me. It fails when trying to compile the installation for conda with the following error message
- Installing terra ...                          FAILED
Error: Error installing package 'terra':
=================================

* installing *source* package 'terra' ...
** package 'terra' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
using C compiler: 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe (conda-forge gcc 14.1.0-0) 14.1.0'
using C++ compiler: 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe (conda-forge gcc 14.1.0-0) 14.1.0'
rm -f terra.dll RcppExports.o RcppFunctions.o RcppModule.o arith.o crs.o distRaster.o distance.o extract.o file_utils.o focal.o gcp.o gdal_algs.o gdal_multidimensional.o gdalio.o geodesic.o geos_methods.o geosphere.o math_utils.o mediancut.o memory.o movingWindow.o ncdf.o ram.o raster_methods.o raster_stats.o rasterize.o read.o read_gdal.o read_ogr.o sample.o sort.o spatBase.o spatDataframe.o spatFactor.o spatRaster.o spatRasterMultiple.o spatSources.o spatTime.o spatVector.o spatVector2.o string_utils.o vecmath.o vecmathse.o vector_methods.o write.o write_gdal.o write_ogr.o
cp -r "C:/Users/wb532468/.conda/envs/RR_WLD_2024_153/Library/share/gdal" ../inst/
cp -r "C:/Users/wb532468/.conda/envs/RR_WLD_2024_153/Library/share/proj" ../inst/
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"C:/Users/wb532468/CONDA~1/envs/RR_WLD~1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/WBG/Rep-checks/RR_WLD_2024_153/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/.renv/1/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Users/wb532468/.conda/envs/RR_WLD_2024_153/Library/include"     -O2 -Wall  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"C:/Users/wb532468/CONDA~1/envs/RR_WLD~1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/WBG/Rep-checks/RR_WLD_2024_153/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/.renv/1/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Users/wb532468/.conda/envs/RR_WLD_2024_153/Library/include"     -O2 -Wall  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppFunctions.cpp -o RcppFunctions.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"C:/Users/wb532468/CONDA~1/envs/RR_WLD~1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/WBG/Rep-checks/RR_WLD_2024_153/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/.renv/1/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Users/wb532468/.conda/envs/RR_WLD_2024_153/Library/include"     -O2 -Wall  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppModule.cpp -o RcppModule.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"C:/Users/wb532468/CONDA~1/envs/RR_WLD~1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/WBG/Rep-checks/RR_WLD_2024_153/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/.renv/1/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Users/wb532468/.conda/envs/RR_WLD_2024_153/Library/include"     -O2 -Wall  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic  -c arith.cpp -o arith.o
In file included from spatVector.h:21,
                 from spatRaster.h:20,
                 from spatRasterMultiple.h:18,
                 from arith.cpp:19:
spatDataframe.h:51:41: error: 'int8_t' was not declared in this scope
   51 |                 std::vector<std::vector<int8_t>> bv;
      |                                         ^~~~~~
spatDataframe.h:28:1: note: 'int8_t' is defined in header '<cstdint>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstdint>'
   27 | #include "spatFactor.h"
  +++ |+#include <cstdint>
   28 | #include <limits>
spatDataframe.h:51:41: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   51 |                 std::vector<std::vector<int8_t>> bv;
      |                                         ^~~~~~
spatDataframe.h:51:41: error: template argument 2 is invalid
spatDataframe.h:51:47: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   51 |                 std::vector<std::vector<int8_t>> bv;
      |                                               ^~
spatDataframe.h:51:47: error: template argument 2 is invalid
spatDataframe.h:68:29: error: 'int8_t' was not declared in this scope
   68 |                 std::vector<int8_t> getB(unsigned i);
      |                             ^~~~~~
spatDataframe.h:68:29: note: 'int8_t' is defined in header '<cstdint>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstdint>'
spatDataframe.h:68:35: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   68 |                 std::vector<int8_t> getB(unsigned i);
      |                                   ^
spatDataframe.h:68:35: error: template argument 2 is invalid
spatDataframe.h:79:17: error: 'int8_t' does not name a type
   79 |                 int8_t getBvalue(unsigned i, unsigned j);
      |                 ^~~~~~
spatDataframe.h:79:17: note: 'int8_t' is defined in header '<cstdint>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstdint>'
spatDataframe.h:95:45: error: 'int8_t' was not declared in this scope
   95 |                 bool add_column(std::vector<int8_t> x, std::string name);
      |                                             ^~~~~~
spatDataframe.h:95:45: note: 'int8_t' is defined in header '<cstdint>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstdint>'
spatDataframe.h:95:51: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   95 |                 bool add_column(std::vector<int8_t> x, std::string name);
      |                                                   ^
spatDataframe.h:95:51: error: template argument 2 is invalid
spatDataframe.h:103:48: error: 'int8_t' was not declared in this scope
  103 |                 void insert_column(std::vector<int8_t>, size_t i);
      |                                                ^~~~~~
spatDataframe.h:103:48: note: 'int8_t' is defined in header '<cstdint>'; this is probably fixable by adding '#include <cstdint>'
spatDataframe.h:103:54: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  103 |                 void insert_column(std::vector<int8_t>, size_t i);
      |                                                      ^
spatDataframe.h:103:54: error: template argument 2 is invalid
make: *** [C:/Users/wb532468/CONDA~1/envs/RR_WLD~1/lib/R/etc/x64/Makeconf:272: arith.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'terra'
* removing 'C:/WBG/Rep-checks/RR_WLD_2024_153/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/.renv/1/terra'
install of package 'terra' failed [error code 1]

It seems that a quick fix would be to add #include <cstdint> in spatDataframe.h, but this file is part of the installation of terra and I can't modify it. I also searched for possible solutions on the terra and renv issues and here on SO but I'm a puzzled to see that this is not a common issue. My sense is that combining a setting like this (Windows + conda + renv) is perhaps unusual.
This is the relevant information from my renv lock file:
{
  "R": {
    "Version": "4.3.3",
    "Repositories": [
      {
        "Name": "CRAN",
        "URL": "https://cran.rstudio.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Packages":{
(......)
"terra": {
      "Package": "terra",
      "Version": "1.7-29",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Requirements": [
        "R",
        "Rcpp",
        "methods"
      ],
      "Hash": "89c24bf35c961e047df79dde2eb69224"
    }
}

Here is a bit more of information:

I'm using conda mainly for my R version (4.3.3). I can't use admin rights to install it the usual way and conda provides a nice solution to select my version of R
I use renv for the packages versions, I'm reproducing an environment created on another computer. I use this instead of the direct installation of R packages through conda because conda's library for Windows in R is quite limited. For instance, I need to have terra 1.7-29 and the latest available in conda for Windows as of today is 1.3-22
I also installed RTools43 in my computer. However, R seems to be taking gcc from my conda environment. you can see that in this line: using C compiler: 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe (conda-forge gcc 14.1.0-0) 14.1.0'
Lastly, I initially had another error I reported to renv in this issue. It was solved after I installed GDAL directly from conda. I'm glad that this was solved but I don't know why terra didn't install its non-R dependencies (GDAL, proj) automatically as it usually does

All other packages install without issues, it's just terra that doesn't work. Any thoughts or ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks!

(Conda Forge R Team Member) We're working on getting terra built for Windows R 4.3/4.4 on Conda Forge at the moment (PR). Should hopefully get working in the next couple of days. I.e., you shouldn't need to do any compilation (a key advantage of Conda + R).

that's great to know. Thanks!

@merv, do you have recommendations on how to integrate an installation from terra from Conda Forge with installations of other packages with renv? for example, if terra is listed in an renv lockfile, does it detect automatically that terra was already installed so there are no conflicts? I've looked for documentation on conda-renv integrations but haven't found any yet. Thanks!

It seems that this installation problem has been fixed in terra 1.7.65: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/pull/1368

@nukubiho thanks, but I need to use 1.7-29 to fully recreate the programming env. That's why I'm using conda + renv
